# What does 'semicolon' mean as a unit of size

Tags: terminology, iolanguage

On the [Io home page](http://www.iolanguage.com/) it mentions its small size, but it uses a unit of measure I've not seen before:

> small vm (~10K semicolons)

Is this just the size in characters (~bytes), or is there something more subtle going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a measure of **Logical lines of code**.

Rather than simply counting all lines of code, including comments, blank lines, etc., you only measure the lines that end in a semicolon.  It's a still-simple but more accurate measure of how large a piece of code is.

Comment: But still very inaccurate, since different programmers use different levels of nesting statements.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: that's in fact _precisely_ why "semicolons" are used as a measure. The statements `if (foo) bar();` and `if (foo) { bar(); }` differ in levels of nesting, but not in number of semicolons.

Comment: Ah-ha - yes, I'm familiar with logical lines of code. 'semicolon' isn't very Google friendly (even with extra search terms) - thank goodness for StackOverflow (and people like you!)

Comment: @MSalters: What I mean is `doThingWith(getSomeObject(), getOtherObject(), { technique: "cool", nesting: "deep"}, function(callbackData) { data = callbackData; }); `

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: that's two _statements_, but a lot of _expressions_.

Comment: @MSalter: Ok, I used the wrong word, but that doesn't invalidate my statement that lines of code (logical or not) are not a good measure of code size. If any exists, it's probably the number of bytecode instructions :p